# C concatenating char* with char causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, concatenation

I have this C function here:

```
char *scanTString(char *program, size_t *cursor, char delim)
{
    size_t bSize = 0;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(bSize);

    (*cursor)++;
    for (; *cursor < strlen(program); ++(*cursor))
    {
        if (program[*cursor] != delim)
        {
            buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, bSize++);
            char temp;
            temp = program[*cursor];
            strncat(buffer, &temp, 1);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return buffer;
}

void tokenize(AST *ast, char *program)
{
    ast->tkSize = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(program); i++)
    {
        if (program[i] == '\'' || program[i] == '"')
        {
            char *scaned = scanTString(program, &i, program[i]);

            ast->tkSize++;
            ast->tokens = (Token *)realloc(ast->tokens, ast->tkSize * sizeof(Token));

            ast->tokens[ast->tkSize - 1].type = l_string;
            ast->tokens[ast->tkSize - 1].value.l_string = scaned;
        }
    }
}
```

I found that the program crashes on the 13th line.
Can someone please explain why this is happening?

(Note: I am including all necessary libraries already)

Comment: At the first call of `buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, bSize++);` the `bSize` is still 0 so you don't get a valid buffer that you can use. And don't overlook the string terminator.

Comment: gdb and valgrind, compile with `-ggdb3` should more or less tell you what's gone wrong.

Comment: Never put `strlen` in a `while` or `for` loop test, unless the string is expected to change.  It just keeps iterating over the entire string *every time through the loop*.  It's a commonly seen mistake made by beginners who don't fully understand what `strlen` does, or haven't learned to think algorithmically.

Comment: I changed bSize to have an initial value of 1 as suggested by @WeatherVane, it doesn't segfault anymore but the results aren't completely correct. I ran the `tokenize` function on the following char*: `'test' "another test"` the results are the following: `1�test       *�another test`
I guess the first byte is just some random data as it isn't being overwritten by a character.
How do I fix this now?